# Google Chart vAxis/tooltip format; going from 0.xxxxx to xx.xxx%

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am reading from an API that has values in "0.XXXXX" format and I'd like the vAxis and tooltip values to render in xx.xxx% format.

using: `vAxis: {format: 'x,xxx%'}` (doc example) gives no decimals.
I've tried `vAxis: {format: 'xx.000%'}` (SO answers to get a decimal suggestion 'xx.0%')but it will only go to one decimal spot.

I am at a loss on how to format this properly.

Comment: If you have three decimal places or accuracy, your third decimal place is a significant digit.  Shouldn't you generally avoid dropping significant digits?  If it is not a significant digit, you probably shouldn't be showing it anyway... you can find a great article by Jason Marshall at http://bit.ly/significantdigits

Comment: I realized that I may have misread the question.  If your problem is getting from a decimal number (0.815) to a percent (81.5%), then I think you may need a DataView with a calculated column.  I'm not certain though, I've never had to do this.  Failing that, you could manually change the data with javascript in a for loop before displaying it. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView_setColumns  If this is the direction you need to go, and need more help, I can write something up for that.

Comment: And one last crack at this:  given input of 0.815, (format pattern -> result), (00% -> 82%), (00.0% -> 81.5%), (000.0% -> 081.5%), (##.#% -> 81.5%), (#####.###% -> 81.5%), (####.000% -> 81.500%).